# Restart fixture when it fails

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I wrote a test that passes 95% of the time, failing the other 5%. I still don't know why it fails (my guess is that components are not rendered correctly).

I implemented a page reload call to reload the page and try again, but it's not very reliable.

**What's the best way to restart the fixture in case it fails?**

Here's a sample test that intentionally fails to emulate my selector that works most of the time, but fails sometimes.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWQtB6Xv01Q';

fixture `Portal Experience playback`
  .page `${URL}`;

test('Testing YouTube', async t => {
  await t.click(Selector('.wrong-selector')); // to emulate my unstable test
});
```

Results in

```
✖ Testing YouTube

   1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.
```

**Is it possible to put the test in a for loop and have it break out of the loop in case the test passes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [quarantine mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-q---quarantine-mode) serves this purpose. In this mode, TestCafe will restart a failed test again until it passes or fails 3 times and will consider it failed only if it fails 3 times. Get more details about the quarantine mode in this article: [Quarantine Mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#quarantine-mode).